# How to convert result of sent_tokenizer to list of lists

Tags: pandas, nltk, tokenize

I ran sent_tokenize on a paragraph and was able to retrieve the sentence_tokens. I then need to store these tokens as a list of lists, on which I will perform word_tokenize. I am having trouble generating this list of lists. My result is currently saved in a pandas dataframe. What is the best iteration method as I have to do this for multiple paragraphs?

```
df['Body1'] = df['Body'].apply(sent_tokenize) 

# this grabs the first sentence of the first paragraph
display(df["Body1"].iloc[0][0])
```

Expected output for one paragraph: [[Sentence 1], [Sentence 2], [Sentence n]]

Thanks in advance for the help!

EDIT: I gave this problem a little more thought.

I tried:

```
sents_list = df.Body.tolist() #df.Body is where my paragraphs are stored, one per row.

sents_list2 = [[i] for i in sents_list] # this embedded my paragraph into another list rather than the expected [[Sent1], [Sent2]] pattern.
```

Note: after doing sent_tokenize on my paragraph, if I say sents_list[0][0], it  outputs the first sentence of the first paragraph as expected.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a minimal example including a small toy text and the expected result? Ideally your code can be copied, pasted and run without a lot of modifications.